# Java (Apache POI) : How to retrieve comment/annotation and associated highlighted text from Microsoft Word?

Tags: java, annotations, apache-poi, comments

I have a Microsoft word (.docx) file and trying to retrieve the comments and it's associated highlighted text. Can you pls help.

Attaching picture of the sample word document and the java code for extracting the comments. [ A file with a line "My name is John". The word "John" is highlighted with a comment "Noun" ]

I am able to extract the comments (Noun, Adjective). I would like to extract the text associated with the comment "Noun" (Noun = John, Adjective = great)

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(msWordFilePath));
    XWPFDocument adoc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
    XWPFWordExtractor xwe = new XWPFWordExtractor(adoc);
    XWPFComment[] comments = adoc.getComments();


    for(int idx=0; idx < comments.length; idx++)
    {
        MSWordAnnotation annot = new MSWordAnnotation();
        annot.setAnnotationName(comments[idx].getId());
        annot.setAnnotationValue(comments[idx].getText());
        aList.add(annot);


    }[enter image description here][1]
```